# Is there a way in the WPF Toolkit datagrid to have a header below the column headers but above the first row

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I looking for a way to create an area that indicates a user is at the top row of the WPF Toolkit datagrid.  (Showing the scrollbar scrolled down is not enough for the user).  I need something that sticks out and says "this is the top row" basically. Messing with the entities that that the grid is bound to will not work for me because I have several grids with different filters over the same collection of entities.  Also this underlying collections is changing while the app is running.

Is there a way to add a control of some sort between the column headers and the first row of the datagrid?  Maybe a separator of some sort?

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to create your own Template for the column headers with ColumnHeaderTemplate and show whatever you need in there. This way you'll have full control of what your header looks like.

Another hackish solution could be you change the Style of the header to achieve the desired effect, like setting the bottom margin to a higher value so that there is a space between the header and the first row.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response - I want to be able to show the etxra space only when the user is scrolled to the top of the grid.  I believe the header solution would always be there no matter where they are scrolled.